# How to extract only first and last name by removing the middle name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display only First and Last name. Sometimes there will be a middle name comes. In that case i need remove the middle name and join first and last name.How is it possible using JavaScript.
The name comes to a variable from database like

```
var displayname="abc pqr xyz"
```

i just need "abc xyz" to a variable .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could split on white space and take the first and last element of the array.

```
var displayname = "abc pqr xyz";
var tmp = displayname.split(" ");
displayname = tmp[0] + " " + tmp[tmp.length-1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression keeping only the 1st and 3rd groups ...

```
var displayname = "abc pqr xyz";
var newname = displayname.replace(/(\w+\s+)(\w+\s+)(\w+)/, '$1$3');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing in another regular expression answer, which I think would have less overhead than splitting.  This will work for any number--including zero--of middle names.

```
var name = "abc def ghi jkl";
var re = /^(\w+ ).*?(\w+)$/;
name.search(re);
alert(RegExp.$1 + " " + RegExp.$2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d1L3vqc5/

Answer (score 1):

```
var displayname = "abc pqr xyz";
var d = displayname.replace(/\s+\w+\s/g, " "); 
console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if first name consists of a two or more words (like 'Anna Maria Middle_Name Last_Name')...

```
var displayname = "abc pqr xyz";
var tmp = displayname.split(/\s+/);
if (tmp.length > 2)
    tmp.splice(-2, 1);
alert(tmp.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()` method and take the first and last array element

```
var displayname="abc pqr xyz";
var result = displayname.split(" ");
alert( result[0]+" "+ result[2] );
```

Answer (score 0):

To only get the first name and last name you can first `.split` the string by the space so it turns into an array. And  then you get the first and last name and add it together.

```
const displayname = "abc pqr xyz";
const splitDisplayName = displayname.split(" ");
const newDisplayName = splitDisplayName[0] + " " + splitDisplayName[2];
```